# SQL Server : selecting rows based on values gathered in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologise if the question isn't all that clear, but it's a relatively hard one to word in a space as short as the title.

Imagine you have a table as below:

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| ID |  Name   |    Country     |
+----+---------+----------------+
|  1 | James   | Mexico         |
|  2 | Peter   | South Africa   |
|  3 | Paul    | Mexico         |
|  4 | Colonel | Panama         |
|  5 | James   | United Kingdom |
|  6 | Hannah  | United Kingdom |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

What I want to do is run a query that says grab me anyone named James, and anyone who is living in the same country as someone called James. In this case it would return:

```
+----+--------+----------------+
| ID |  Name  |    Country     |
+----+--------+----------------+
|  1 | James  | Mexico         |
|  3 | Paul   | Mexico         |
|  5 | James  | United Kingdom |
|  6 | Hannah | United Kingdom |
+----+--------+----------------+
```

While this example might seem somewhat nonsensical, it is based on a real issue of course, but a simplification.

In reality, much like this table (although the rules assigned don't make this clear), there will always be a 'James' before there is anyone else in James's country - so for example swapping James from Mexico will always be before Paul from Mexico in this table.

In fact, in most cases Paul from Mexico will be directly after James from Mexico, although this is not guaranteed.

So what syntax can allow me to perform a query like this? Is the only possible way to do it going to be returning the list of James(es?) and then running a separate query using WHERE country = mexico || united kingdom

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution, `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.Country = t1.Country
                and t2.Name = 'James')
```

Or, do a self `JOIN`:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select distinct Country from tablename where Name = 'James') t2
  on t2.Country = t1.Country
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (Name nvarchar(100), Country nvarchar(100))


INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
(N'James',N'Mexico'),
(N'Peter',N'South Africa'),
(N'Paul',N'Mexico'),
(N'Colonel',N'Panama'),
(N'James',N'United Kingdom'),
(N'Hannah',N'United Kingdom')


SELECT t2.*
FROM @Test AS t
INNER JOIN @Test AS t2 ON t.Country = t2.Country
WHERE t.Name = N'James'
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple query I can think of here is a query with an `IN` clause:

```
select *
from mytable
where country in (select country from mytable where name = 'James');
```